# Tips for earning reputation

Tags: discussion

I am not sure that whether this is a right place to ask.

How to earn reputation quickly for a new user?

I am looking for some tips.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There really are no short cuts -- it should be self evident, but the best ways to earn reputation are:

#### Ask good questions

Good questions are well-thought out, and show evidence of research and analysis of the problem.
They also usually involve something that can not be solved/answered by simply reading the manual or typing the title of your question into Google.

---

#### Provide good answers

Good answers are well-researched. They address the problem and explain best practices to resolve it. They also explain the ***why***, not just the how (teach a man to fish...).

Comment: I cannot upvote this enough.

Answer (score 6):

Use some of the advanced search features to find unanswered questions in tags that you believe you are well-versed in or have an interest in.

For example, I like answering questions about Linux so I might perform a query like this `[linux] answers:0 closed:0` ([link](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%5Blinux%5D%20answers:0%20closed:0&submit=search)).  This will give me lots of unanswered Linux questions that haven't been closed.  Then simply browse through the questions, find a question you know the answer for, and provide a good answer.